# Error in xamarin.kotlin.stdlib ($ReflectSdkVersion is defined multiple times) after migration from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: java, android, kotlin, xamarin.forms, maui

For last few days i;m fighting with migrating my app from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI.
I solved dozens of errors already but this one - i cannot wrap my head around.

Error:

```
MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Error in .nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlin.stdlib\1.8.10\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10.jar:kotlin/internal/jdk7/JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion.class:
MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Type kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion is defined multiple times: .nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlin.stdlib\1.8.10\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10.jar:kotlin/internal/jdk7/JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion.class, .nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlin.stdlib.jdk7\1.7.20.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20.jar:kotlin/internal/jdk7/JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion.class
java.exe error JAVA0000: Compilation failed
java.exe error JAVA0000: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: .nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlin.stdlib\1.8.10\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10.jar
2>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: kotlin/internal/jdk7/JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion.class
```

Followed by hundreds of warnings such as:

```
2>JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
2>JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY
2>JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY
2>JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
```

My android .csproj Packages (i suspect nugets)

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
 <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
 <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
 <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
 <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
 <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>

<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">29.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
     <EnableLLVM>true</EnableLLVM>
     <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
     <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
     <!--<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>
     <AndroidLinkTool>r8</AndroidLinkTool>-->
     <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
     <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>false</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-android|AnyCPU'">
     <Optimize>True</Optimize>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-android|AnyCPU'" />
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup" Version="3.1.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="FirebaseAuthentication.net">
       <Version>4.0.2</Version>
     </PackageReference>
     <PackageReference Include="Refractored.MvvmHelpers" Version="1.6.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl">
       <Version>1.8.116</Version>
     </PackageReference>
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation" Version="1.6.0.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView">
       <Version>1.3.0</Version>
     </PackageReference>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers" Version="0.4.421302">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
     </PackageReference>
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime" Version="2.7.1.5" />
     <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" Version="118.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
<!--<ProguardConfiguration Include="proguard.cfg" />-->
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Found another issue that might link to the solution: 
2>        JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX
2>        reason: class file for androidx.annotation.RestrictTo$Scope not found

Comment: Check in VS, under Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager, if you have the selected version of the OS installed

Comment: Did you try to set the `<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>` as net6.0-android? I have checked the  xamarin.kotlin.stdlib package and found it support .net6.0 not .net7.0.

Comment: Yeah, going with net6.0 together with implicitly including xamarin.kotlin.stdlib JDK7 for version 1.8.0 solved this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

- Downgrading entire solution from net7.0 to net6.0
- Implicitly including xamarin.kotlin.stdlib JDK7 (and JDK8 just in case) for version 1.8.0.